# Check if element is not displayed - WebDriverJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriverjs

Using `selenium` and `webdriverJS` I want to create a test to check if an element is not displayed on the page. To check if one or more elements are present, I decided to use the `isDisplayed()` function:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.element')).isDisplayed();
```

- Do you know a similar function that returns `true` if the elements if the element is **NOT** displayed?
- `isDisplayed()` works well when used on a single `element`. Is there a similar way to check if multiple elements are displayed?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions -

- No, there is no function which returns true if element is absent. You can check for negative(false) condition on the existing `isDisplayed()` method. You can use various test frameworks with webdriverjs and perform the false assertions like jasmine, mocha, etc... [How to use webdriverjs with Mocha](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Writing_Tests) and [testing with jasmine](http://engineering.wingify.com/posts/e2e-testing-with-webdriverjs-jasmine/)
- If you want to check if multiple elements are displayed then you can either use inbuilt loops like [`.each()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) or [`.map()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) or [`.reduce()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce)(applicable only if you have multiple elements that you can get using a single locator) or you have to check them individually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I just have one further question: is there a syntax similar to `jasmine`'s `.not` to check for the negative condition of a function or method?

Comment: There is no such thing in webdriverjs. However you can still use Jasmine with webdriverjs and use such shortcuts. Or you can also use Mocha test framework too.

Comment: They force me to use `jasmine` so I have to stick with it :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

> isDisplayed() works well when used on a single element. Is there a
>   similar way to check if multiple elements are displayed?

This can be solved by using [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map). Example:

```
element.all(by.css(".element")).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.isDisplayed();
});
```

This would return a promise resolving into an array of booleans.

If you want a single boolean value, you can use [`reduce()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce):

```
element.all(by.css(".element")).reduce(function (acc, elm) {
    return elm.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
        return isDisplayed && acc;
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: Hey man, nice to see you again :) I will check it out, but a question first: is it also possible to use `Protractor` terminology with `Jasmine`?

Comment: @d_z90 well, if your web-site is non-angular, you can still use protractor and it's syntactic sugar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I show how I solved the issue, using `jasmine`, in case that someone may need it in the future:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.element')).isDisplayed()
    .then(function(displayed) {
        expect(displayed).not.toBe(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution working. Code evaluates presense of element and return true or false. Then I could evaluate this value and perform other stuff on a page.
Still have some small error : Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
`

```
const exit =await driver.findElement(By.css('input[id^="Login"] ')).then(
()=>{return true} ). catch((err=> { if(err.name=== "NoSuchElementError") return false;
throw new Error (" No such element")}));

const check= (elem) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject)=> {
        setTimeout(elem=> { 
            if( elem ===true) {resolve('HA-HA-HA') }
            else {reject(new Error('Not ha-ha-ha'))}
        },500,elem)

       })
   };
`
```